# Mongoose Proper Syntax to Find by Child ID

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Using the model.find method I can find documents that match all properties defined within my schema except when a property has a type of mongoose.Schema.ObjectId. In my case, references to the owner of the document. I've tried all sorts of ways to get documents by the owner _id but nothing is working. Anybody know the proper way to do this ?

--EDIT--

Just in case anybody runs into the same issue, I got it working using the following query.

**Query:**

```
const users_cars = await Cars.find( { owner: user_id } );
```

**Schema:**

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: Object,
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: [ true, 'car must belong to an owner' ]
    },
    name: String
});
```

Comment: Please provide sample JSON data as seen by mongoshell

Comment: Thanks for trying to help... I got it sorted out !!